# how to add icon in menu items in action bar android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

My problem is how it is add the icon in menu items in `ActionBar` android.if we declare the app:showAsAction="never"

My code is

```
<item android:id="@+id/twitID"
            android:title="twitter"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/twitter"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
```

it show only title.
it's not working.please help me.
Thank u.

Comment: Change `app:showAsAction` to `"ifRoom"` or `"always"`. (This is from my self-experience for native `ActionBar` only. Not tested on `v7-compat`)

Answer (score 3):

You should change showAsAction to `showAsAction="always"` or `showAsAction="ifRoom"` and it will automatically put your item to the `ActionBar` as an item with icon.

If you want to show the item in the `overflow menu` not in the `ActionBar` as an item, then you should `inflate` a `PopUp` manually with custom layout. Then you can put whatever you want. But it is not simplest thing to do.

Comment: k.how to add that custom layout to the overflow menu.give me any example.

Comment: Do you think that this can be helpful? https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/9345938#file-iconizedmenu-java-L55